# Codility worng answer on TapeEquilibrium for php

Tags: php

I just coded a solution for the TapeEquilibrium problem in php. The thing is i`m getting some wrong answers for the automatic code revitions provided by Codility.
The link to the finished test is

https://codility.com/demo/results/demo2G35FU-EJQ/.

Any idea whats the `two elements` wrong answer error?
Is it necessary to type (typecast) the variables in php for this test? i mean, how do u tell the compiler X variable is double or int in php? Thx a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two elements test case is probably {-1000, 1000}. This array can be splited only in one place and the distance is `|-1000-1000| = 2000`. Your program for this input returns 0, because in the second iteration of the for loop $arr_h is 0 and $sum_total is also 0.

Simply change condition in loop `for ($i = $count_-1; $i > 0 ; $i--)` to get 100%.

Answer (score 0):

"Two elements" test case is {-1000, 1000}, additional testing (if (N == 2)) can be performed to solve this issue.
"Small elements" test case should be passed after setting a starting value to **tmp** variable  (take a look at my example) prior to entering in the second loop. My example is on C, but it can be easily implementing in other languages:

```
int TapeEquilibrium(int A[], int N) {

    long long sum = 0;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int min = 1000;

    if (N == 2) {
        return abs(A[0] - A[1]);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        sum += A[i];
    }

    long long left = 0;
    long long right = sum;
    int tmp = abs(left - right);

    for(j = 1; j < N; j++)
    {
        right -= A[j - 1];
        left += A[j - 1];
        tmp = abs(left - right);
        if (min > tmp)
        {
            min = tmp;
        }
    }

    return min;
}
```